# The structure of the second half of this sentence

Tags: sentence

> The dot is placed in a position that is relative to the other dots and
>   the timing as to when the item was posted

I'm okay with the first half of this sentence (the part before *and*). I'm wondering if the second half is a legitimate ellipsis here. If so, how does it interact with the first half? In other words, what could be the full form of the entire sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possibilities.**

The dot is placed in a position that is relative to the other dots,  and **also with regard to** the timing as to when the item was posted.

The dot is placed in a position that is relative to the other dots, and the timing **positioned**  as to when the item was posted.

I favour the former as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the flexibility of not using a complete sentence?

> The dot is placed in a position that is relative to:
>
> - The other dots
> - The timing when the item was posted

Or, if you must have a sentence, how about

> The dot is placed in a position that is relative to both the other
>   dots, and the timing when the item was posted.